# How to put something other than a string in a placeholder or value (a vue property)

Tags: html, vue.js, input, pug, nuxt.js

I'm creating a CMS with nuxt and pug/jade and i want to efficiëntly make a list of inputs for the user to post information in.
I wanted to render the list with `v-for` and then add a value and placeholder with the property of each `item` in `items`.

This is what i tried:

```
li(v-for="item in items" :key="item.message")
  input(type="text" placeholder="item.message" value="item.message")

data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { message: 'Voornaam' },
        { message: 'Tussenvoegsel' },
        { message: 'Achternaam' },
        { message: 'Telefoonnummer' },
        { message: 'E-mailadres' },
        { message: 'NSP nbr.' },
        { message: 'Type pers' },
        { message: 'Bedrijf' },
        { message: 'Publiceert bij' }
      ]
    } 
  }
```

Currently they just turn into a literal string of item.message instead of .e.g. value="Voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind that attributes to that fields using `v-bind:` or just `:` :

```
 input(type="text" :placeholder="item.message" :value="item.message")
```